# Android App does not work on other device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I install my app with android studio it perfectly runs fine on my device, But when I **share** the same app with my friend or anyone It didn't even **Install** on their phone.

It show this type of error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVLF9.jpg)

Comment: Gee: it sounds like you need to 1) identify what model# and Android version your friend has, 2) Create an AVD with the same version (or plug in the actual device with a USB cable),  and 3) debug with Android Studio (look at the logcat, etc). There are MANY possible reasons for "App not installed" - you must troubleshoot!

Comment: What kind of apk did you give to your friends? Debug or Release?

Comment: Active Debugging mode in your friends devices and try again.

Comment: Debug apk.I shared app directly through telegram.

Comment: how are you sharing your apk? through email or by other means?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are sharing non signed apk release file of you android application. Please follow instructions mentioned at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing for creating singed apk version of your application.

Comment: This is just one of many possible causes.

Comment: I tried sending signed apk but still it doesn't install on anyone's phone

Answer (score 0):

**There can be many reasons**

- check your lowest Android version in Gradle file
- How you shipping the apk

Some people have answered to your question try that

And if your app is open source then share the project with me
I'll have a look and test in different devices

Also

If your friend has xiaomi phone then apk will not install. solution : you need to sign the apk (you can google this) before sending